# How to fetch the row from MySQL having latest date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table "poem" with fields "dated","content" etc.

I want to get the content of the recent dated field.

```
$sql="select content, max(dated) as latestDate from poem";
```

This is not working.

Comment: `ORDER BY dated DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just one row, use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select p.*
from poem p
order by dated desc
limit 1;
```

If you want all rows with the most recent date:

```
select p.*
from poem p
where p.dated = (select max(dated) from poem);
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply have to order by the date

```
SELECT * FROM TABLENAME ORDER BY DATE DESC
```